# Background image not appearing

Tags: customization, images, custom-background, add-theme-support

I'm trying to add a custom background on a child theme. In the child theme's functions.php, I add `add_theme_support( 'custom-background');` and the background option appears under the "Appearance" menu as expected. I add the image that I want, save, and nothing happens. The image won't appear as the background. What am I doing wrong?

Using version 4.3.1.

This is all that's in my child theme's function.php"

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}

add_theme_support( 'custom-background');
```

Comment: Are you sure its not just visually hidden?  Search the source for the image name.

Answer (score 0):

custom background can be used in below way:

```
  $defaults = array(
  'default-color'          => '',
  'default-image'          => '',
  'default-repeat'         => '',
  'default-position-x'     => '',
  'default-attachment'     => '',
  'wp-head-callback'       => '_custom_background_cb',
  'admin-head-callback'    => '',
  'admin-preview-callback' => ''
  );
 add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $defaults );
```

Example usage:

```
 $args = array(
  'default-color' => '000000',
  'default-image' => '%1$s/images/testback.jpg',
 );

add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $args );
```

Example output when you will view source:

```
 <style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css"> body.custom-background { background-color: #bdd96e; }
```

[For details follow link:](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Backgrounds)

Output:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried this method too. It still doesn't work. Specifically, I wrote:

`$args = array(
 'default-color' => '000000',
 'default-image' => '../../uploads/2015/10/bg_image.jpg',
);

add_theme_support('custom-background', $args);`

Comment: If you want to add from admin section like from appearance tab then you need to look at code file :

/wordpress/wp-admin/custom-background.php

Comment: Please view source of your page source, above function will return path like below:
http://yoursite/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/images/bg_image.jpg

And just use the same one I given in answer by replacing your image name.